# Twitter Tweet or ReTweet Callbacks

Tags: twitter, tweets

Hope you are having a good time.
I am creating a website where when users Tweet a wordpress blog entry then they get points on the websites.

So basically, if a user Tweets that entry on his Twitter then we would give him some points to use on the website (not money). Although this thing is plausible with Facebook but not with Twitter in my knowledge.

I am willing to try to both ways by Twitter Tweet Button or TweetMeme Retweet Facility. However, I could not find a facility for a callback at neither of these.

I am implementing a similar functionality in Facebook and I can see the light at the end of the tunnel with using FBML JS SDK. HOwever, if something similar can be achieved with Twitter then it would be awesome.

Would love to hear more from you guys,

Kind Regards,

Khuram

Answer (score 3):

They've fixed this with the intents function:

https://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents-events

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
// Do something there
});
```

or for clicking

```
twttr.events.bind('click', function(event) {
var click_type = event.region;
});
```

Comment: on events.bind('tweet'... is there any information actually returned in the event? I keep getting null.

Answer (score 2):

using Twitters @anywhere api, you can set an onTweet function that does something when someone tweets.

here is a [6-step tutorial](http://blancer.com/tutorials/26897/using-twitter%E2%80%99s-anywhere-service-in-6-steps/), see number 4

A default tweetBox can be called after the element with the comments class with the following snippet.

```
twttr.anywhere(function(twitter) {
    twitter(".comments").tweetBox();
});
```

So if you want a custom label, content, and a callback when the tweet has been sent, use this code.

```
twitter(".comments").tweetBox({
    label: 'What do you think about this article?',
    defaultContent: '#nettuts ',
    onTweet: function(plain, html){
        // Actions when tweet is sent
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jim,

I will give that a try.

Regards,

Comment: Hi Jim, I couldnt make it work. Could you provide with a sample code for me to include?

Answer (score 0):

opening tweet intent pop from JS code will send a callback. You need to put your tweet URL in herf of anchor tag

**HTML:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=itismytext&url=http://google.com"> twitter share</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        // OR
        alert(JSON.stringify(event));
    });

});
```

Comment: `tweetid` is not defined here