# Twitter Javascript API: adding Web Intent events

Tags: javascript, events, twitter

I need to handle 'tweet' event. That is what I have now, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function jsTweet() {

   // some other stuf here
   // ...

   var urlTW = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text&url=http://my_url.com";
   var winTW = window.open(urlTW,'','toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=360');
}

(function() {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
        alert('tweet!!!!');
    });
}());
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="jsTweet();">
```

Comment: I have answered similar question on following thread. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600217/twitter-tweet-or-retweet-callbacks/12686259#12686259][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600217/twitter-tweet-or-retweet-callbacks/12686259#12686259

Answer (score 0):

Several things :

1/ Close your anchor tag.

2/ Your anonymous function is called only when the page is loaded. The `twttr` object doesn't exist at this time. So there is no binding done. Debug your function with Firebug or something, this should appear as an error.

Comment: Binding is done, for sure. When i change link to <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text&url=http://my_url.com"> all is going well. But I need to show tweet popup as in example above, because I have some other things to do before showing it.

Comment: Binding is not done in your function jsTweet();. It is outside of it. When a click is done, the anonymous function will NOT execute. Also, there are some weird things about your anonymous function. It should be something like `(function() { ... })();` if you want it to be executed on page load. In your example, your anonymous function is never executed.

Comment: Let us assume, that anchor will be clicked only once and jsTweet code will be
`fucntion jsTweet() {
   var urlTW = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text&url=http://my_url.com";
   window.open(urlTW,'','params');
   twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) { alert('tweet!!!!'); });
}`
But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I am not familiar with the twitter API, but it seems weird to me that this 'twttr' object suddenly exists just like that. Where is it defined? What is it?

Comment: This is twitter bug. They will try to fix it, but they don't give me any estimation.